# Detect if the first letter of each word is upper with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string, for example:

**Hello World today is Thursday**

I want my regex match only the letters: H, W and T.

Please, someone can help me to do this with Javascript.

Thanks !

Comment: `string.match(/[A-Z]/g)`

Comment: So the expected output is only those words that start with upper case letter H W and T

Comment: Oh my !! I had forgotten to use "g". Thanks !

Comment: Maybe `(?:([A-Z])?(?:[a-z]+ ?))+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
var string = 'Hello World today is Thursday';
string.match(/\b[A-Z]/g);
    // \b matches the beginning of the word
    // [A-Z] matches only capital letters
    // g makes it a greedy search that searches the entire string for all matches, rather than just first.

// returns ['H','W','T']
```

And if you're looking to get the full word, rather than just the first letter, you can add \w+ to match all non-whitespace characters after each capital.

```
var string = 'Hello World today is Thursday';
string.match(/\b[A-Z]\w+/g);
// returns ['Hello', 'World', 'Thursday']
```

Comment: What about, if i want to know at the end of each word? For example: hellO worlD today is thursdaY. I want to returns: O, D, Y

Comment: To match the end of the word you could flip the [A-Z] and \b, like this:

    string.match(/[A-Z]\b/g)

Comment: You can even add on the \w+ to the beginning to get the full word.
string.match(/\w+[A-Z]\b/g)

Comment: And one more question, what about if I want to combine these two methods

Comment: In that case you would just combine the two:  string.match(/\b[A-Z]\w+[A-Z]/g)

Comment: @Mercury +1 (because you have the lowest score :) )

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `\b` regex token to define word boundaries. Pair this up with ensuring that the first letter is in the range A-Z and you're set. This will give you an array containing words which have the first letter upper-cased, then you can do whatever you want with it:

```
str.match(/\b([A-Z])\w*?\b/g, str);
```

Answer (score 2):

To quickly detect if every word is captalized you could compare your string against a capitalized version:

```
function capitalize(str) {
    return str.replace(/^.|\b./g, function(match) {
        return match.toUpperCase();
    });
}

var str = 'Hello World today is Thursday';

console.log(capitalize(str) === str); // false

str = 'Hello World Today Is Thursday';

console.log(capitalize(str) === str); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

**Character Class: Match Only the Letters `H`, `W` and `T`**

You can use this simple regex:

```
[HWT]
```

The brackets create a character class that mean "match one of the characters inside the class".

For instance, to get the first match:

```
var myregex = /[HWT]/;
var matchArray = myregex.exec(yourString);
if (matchArray != null) {
    thematch = matchArray[0];
} else {
    thematch = "";
}
```